# I am having difficulty maintaining a wpa handshake (4 way handshake) airodump-ng

Tags: wpa2, aircrack-ng

```
Ifconfig wlo1
ifconfig wlo1 down
iwconfig wlo1 mode monitor
ifconfig wlo1 up
airmon-ng check wlo1
kill processes


Airodump-ng wlo1
airodump-ng -c (channel) -w (file) --bssid  wlo1 
aireplay-ng -0 0 -a (mac) wlo1
```

I have received the handshake only a handful of times. If anybody has any advice or insight that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The formatting of your question is quite confusing. Are the first two sentences a series of commands you have run? Not separating them by line makes it pretty difficult to understand what you are trying to convey.

Answer (score 1):

You could sniff packet using wireshark and check if your NIC is sending those packets. Anyway, I would recommend not to use aireplay with the second 0, maybe someone is trying to start the 4-way handshake and you send him a deauth packet (it is not very likely, but it could happens).

Answer (score 0):

From what it looks like in your question you aren't deauthorizing any users off the network. So that means the only way you would intercept a handshake is if someone joined the network on their own (Like just walked into wifi range or change to that wifi). If you deauth people from their own network they might notice, but the most people might just think it was their wifi being crappy.

To deauth people using Aircrack the code looks something like this.

```
aireplay-ng --deauth 5 -a (enter BSSID of AP here) -c (enter MAC targeted client here) wlan0
```

5 is the number of deauthorization packets it sends out, you can put more if you aren't sure it's been actually been booted off the network.

This link should help you with any other questions you might have about deauthing people with [Aircrack](https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=deauthentication)

Another issue could be the distance, if you are too far from the device itself you could have just missed the handshake all together.

Comment: The aireplay-ng -0 0 -a (bssid) is the deauth process I was taught. The second 0 being an Infinite loop rather than the 5 you mentioned. I'll give it a try but got some reason the way I was doing it has worked for months and all of a sudden it stopped. 

Thanks for the info. 

Evan